# Compile assets with Laravel Mix Error on Laravel 5.4 and Node.js

Tags: node.js, laravel, ubuntu, npm, plesk

To make npm globally I ran in the CLI: `export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/7/bin:$PATH` on Ubuntu (I have Plesk installed).

Without not much knowledge I ran `npm run watch` in the application path but I got several errors:

> user@server:~/avisos.pagina$ npm run watch
>
> @ watch /var/www/vhosts/pagina/avisos.pagina
>   cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> sh: 1: cross-env: not found
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85
>
> npm ERR! argv "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm" "run" "watch"
>
> npm ERR! node v7.4.0
>
> npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
>
> npm ERR! file sh
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn
>
> npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
>
> npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
>
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>
> npm ERR!     npm bugs
>
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /var/www/vhosts/pagina/avisos.pagina/npm-debug.log

When I read `/var/www/vhosts/pagina/avisos.pagina/npm-debug.log` this is what I see:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ '/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node',
>
> 1 verbose cli   '/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'bugs' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@4.0.5
>
> 3 info using node@v7.4.0
>
> 4 silly fetchPackageMetaData .
>
> 5 silly fetchDirectoryPackageData .
>
> 6 silly bugs url https://www.npmjs.org/package/
>
> 7 verbose stack Error: spawn xdg-open ENOENT
>
> 7 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>
> 7 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>
> 7 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
>
> 7 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>
> 7 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>
> 8 verbose cwd /var/www/vhosts/pagina/avisos.pagina
>
> 9 error Linux 4.9.36-x86_64-linode85
>
> 10 error argv "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/7/bin/npm" "bugs"
>
> 11 error node v7.4.0
>
> 12 error npm  v4.0.5
>
> 13 error path xdg-open
>
> 14 error code ENOENT
>
> 15 error errno ENOENT
>
> 16 error syscall spawn xdg-open
>
> 17 error enoent spawn xdg-open ENOENT
>
> 18 error enoent spawn xdg-open ENOENT
>
> 18 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> 18 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

And now in my website I can see this instead the Laravel 5.4 website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO4wU.png

I've tried to run `find /var/www/vhosts/pagina/avisos.pagina --name package.json` and is not being found anywhere. Any ideas to compile assets with Laravel Mix without crashing the app or how to make this work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sometimes works is deleting the `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` again before running `npm run watch` if that still wont work try `npm run watch-poll` instead

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I get this message on `npm install`: `Killed         ....] - extract:vue: sill doParallel extract 1026`

Comment: @apokryfos, It was a CPU issue, but the Phusion Passenger error still showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running Ubuntu, odds are good the `cross-env` part of the command is tripping up your NPM. I've run into this issue numerous times and found removing `cross-env` (which, IIRC, is a fix/workaround for Windows boxes, so if you're not running Windows anywhere, it's not necessary) to fix it. Alternatively (or if you are running Windows), you should be able to install `cross-env` with `npm install -g cross-env`.

I've found it helpful to run the node commands directly when I run into problems, so I get the errors themselves. In this case:

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

If my suspicion is correct, you'll want to convert it to:

```
NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

Things like `npm run watch` are simply shortcuts to these longer scripts. These shortcuts are declared in your `package.json` file (where you can also define your own script shortcuts if you want).